# EWS Displays Emails very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Services in my Application Code to display list of emails on application UI. However, it is able to retrieve emails list. But it takes very very long to display all set. If I decrease number of emails to display it takes less time to display.

```
public static List<EmailMsg> GetEmailListInFolder(string folderName)
    {
        var folderId = GetFolderId(folderName);
        var service = GetExchangeService();

        if (folderId != null)
        {
            var emails = new List<EmailMsg>();
            var count = 0;
            var findResults = service.FindItems(folderId, new ItemView(100));

            foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
            {
                var emailPropertySet = new PropertySet(
                    BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
                    new PropertyDefinitionBase[]{
                            new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(4115, MapiPropertyType.Binary)
                    });

                var message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, emailPropertySet);

                emails.Add(new EmailMsg(folderName, count++, item.Id.UniqueId, message.Subject, message.DateTimeReceived.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"), ""));
            }
            return emails;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I debug code and found out that it takes few seconds on this line to before proceeding to next line.

```
var message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, emailPropertySet);
```

Kindly, suggest me a way to decrease the loading time of my email items. Thanks

Comment: In order to find what is slowing the bind enumerate the `emailPropertySet`  and bench mark a bind with only one of those at a time. My bet on you are loading big attachements.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898269/how-can-i-reduce-ews-calls-when-downloading-attachments-from-an-inbox , if not dupe

Answer (score 0):

You are returning all the `BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties`!
You might want to consider changing this to just return the properties you need.

List of FirstClassProperties from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/email-properties-and-elements-in-ews-in-exchange):

```
Id
ParentFolderId
ItemClass
Subject
Sensitivity
Body
Attachments
DateTimeReceived
Size
Categories
Importance
InReplyTo
IsSubmitted
IsDraft
IsFromMe
IsResend
IsUnmodified
InternetMessageHeaders
DateTimeSent
DateTimeCreated
AllowedResponseActions
ReminderDueBy
IsReminderSet
ReminderMinutesBeforeStart
DisplayCc
DisplayTo
HasAttachments
Culture
EffectiveRights
LastModifiedName
LastModifiedTime
IsAssociated
WebClientReadFormQueryString
WebClientEditFormQueryString
ConversationId
Flag
InstanceKey
EntityExtractionResult
Sender
ToRecipients
CcRecipients
BccRecipients
IsReadReceiptRequested
IsDeliveryReceiptRequested
ConversationIndex
ConversationTopic
From
InternetMessageId
IsRead
IsResponseRequested
ReplyTo
References
ReceivedBy
ReceivedRepresenting
```

You are loading the Attachments. To avoid this big load you can either:

- Load the attachement only when you are on a specific mail.
- Load only the properties 
  with [LoadPropertiesForItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems?view=exchange-ews-api)
  and getting the attachments name, extention, etc without getting the real attachement.

  Then getting the real attachment can be done using [`ExchangeService.GetAttachments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getattachments?view=exchange-ews-api)